# Get the value in table cell with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've the table as follows :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="lanpaizt-tab">
                <tr class="lanpaizt-tr1">
                    <td class="wid70">id</td>
                    <td class="wid150">nickname</td>
                    <td class="wid150">account</td>
                    <td class="wid150">mail</td>
                    <td class="wid100">tel</td>
                    <td>operate</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" id="member_id">2</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">lisi</td>   
                    <td>dksdkl</td>
                    <td>dka@gmail.com</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">123456</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">
                        <button class="editbtn"></button>
                        <button class="deletebtn"></button>
                    </td> 
                </tr>         
                <tr>
                    <td>sdlsd</td>
                    <td>ndjksa@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>

</table>
```

I want to get value of cell which id is "member_id" with two ways but failed:

1.

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

    var user_id = $(this).closest('#member_id').text()
    console.log(user_id)
})
```

2.

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

    var user_id = $(this).closest('tr').siblings('#member_id').text()
    console.log(user_id)
})
```

Both of them get the empty value. What's wrong with my code? Is there any other way to get it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem in your approach is,`#member_id` is sibling of delete buttons immediate parent `td`. You should traverse to parent element and find its sibling using:

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

  var user_id = $(this).parent().siblings('#member_id').text()
  console.log(user_id)
});
```

Also IDs are(should be) unique. you can simply use get the element using id selector.the need for traversing and finding will be eliminated:

```
var user_id = $('#member_id').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:http://jsfiddle.net/ouL1p1k9/

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

    var user_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('#member_id').text()
    alert(user_id)
});
```

OR

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

        var user_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text()
        alert(user_id)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(this).closest('#member_id').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Id's must be unique through out the DOM and you should directly get jquery object using id selector, no need to traverse through elements using methods like `.find()`, `.closest()` etc. see below code -

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

  var user_id = $('#member_id').text()
  console.log(user_id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not great but a solution for this is as follows:

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

        var user_id = $(this).parent().parent().find('#member_id').text();
        console.log(user_id)
})
```

You could also consider setting the member_id value on the actual delete button:

```
<button class="deletebtn" id='2'></button>
```

And then code your javascript handler like this:

```
$('.deletebtn').click(function(){

        var user_id = $(this).prop('id');
        console.log(user_id)
})
```

But suppose it doesn't really matter too much how you approach this.